# HTTP POST multipart/formdata using HttpClient

Tags: c#, stream, httpclient, multipartform-data, memorystream

When I post the below code using httpclient

```
using var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent("NKdKd9Yk");
using var stream = new MemoryStream();
file.CopyTo(stream);
var fileBytes = stream.ToArray();
formContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
formContent.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "file", fileName);
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(GetDocumentUpdateRelativeUrl(), formContent);
```

here file is of type IFormfile

In API side I retrieve file as follows

```
var base64str= "";
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    request.file.CopyTo(ms);
    var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
    base64str= Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
    // act on the Base64 data
}
```

I get 0 byte. My questions is what's wrong with this approch?

But If I use below code. Then API works and I get what I post.

```
using var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent("NKdKd9Yk");
using var stream = new MemoryStream();
file.CopyTo(stream);
var fileBytes = stream.ToArray();
formContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
formContent.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(fileBytes)), "file", fileName);
```

differece is how I add stream content

```
formContent.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "file", fileName);
vs
formContent.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(fileBytes)), "file", fileName);
```

Why the first approch didn't work but second one does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` in order to jump back to the beginning of the `MemoryStream`. You should also use `CopyToAsync`

In the second version, you had a fresh `MemoryStream` from the `byte[]` array, which is positioned on `0` anyway.

```cs
using var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent("NKdKd9Yk");
using var stream = new MemoryStream();
await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
formContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
formContent.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "file", fileName);
using var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(GetDocumentUpdateRelativeUrl(), formContent);
```

Although to be honest, the `MemoryStream` seems entirely unnecessary here. Just pass the a `Stream` from `file` directly.

```cs
using var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent("NKdKd9Yk");
formContent.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data";
using var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
formContent.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "file", fileName);
using var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(GetDocumentUpdateRelativeUrl(), formContent);
```

Comment: stream.Seek(0); gives error. stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) fix this. new StreamContent(file) does not work as file is of type IFormfile

Comment: Then you can use `file.OpenReadStream()` to get an actual stream. See edit