# Posting file stream and other parameters with form data in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multipartform-data, filestream, http-status-code-400

I am trying to call external POST API with form data and getting always 400 bad request error. The stream can be PDF or ZIP. In the following code the Stream type is `System.IO.Stream`.

```cs
using (MultipartFormDataContent formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
{
    // Add file content
    formData.Add(new StringContent(summerymodel.author.fullName), "file.author.fullName");
    formData.Add(new StringContent(summerymodel.category.guid), "file.category.guid");
    formData.Add(new StringContent(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(summerymodel.description)?"": summerymodel.description), "file.description");
    formData.Add(new StringContent(summerymodel.edition + 1), "file.edition");
    formData.Add(new StringContent(summerymodel.format), "file.format");
    formData.Add(new StringContent("false"), "file.private");
    formData.Add(new StringContent("File"), "file.storageMethodName");
    formData.Add(new StringContent("Test-Title"), "file.title");
    formData.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "file.content", "TestFile.pdf");
    // Send POST request to the API
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(editionUrl, formData);

    // Check if the response is successful
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Read response content as string
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Response from API: " + responseString);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("API request failed with status code: " + response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the body of the response in the error case also. Maybe the server tells you there what he does not like about your request. Or do you you have access to the server and simply can check the server logs that hopefully exists?

Comment: "Stream type is System.IO.Stream" that is always the case or it wouldn't be a stream. Stream is abstract so you definitely have something derived from Stream not Stream itself. Presumably a FileStream you tagged the question with that.

Comment: Try setting the content type: formData.Headers.ContentType.MediaType = "multipart/form-data"; Also, what is the "stream" object? see this link for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72853828/http-post-multipart-formdata-using-httpclient